# Is there a way to track change in response over time and map that onto changes in response of another category in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dummy-variable, melt, change-tracking

(I'm SUPER new to coding in general so all suggestions are much appreciated.)
So I'm working with a data set that contains panel survey data that was posed to the same 8000 participants 7 times over the course of the last decade. I currently have dummy variable forms for the answers I'm interested in, so now my data is looks like this:

| colour2011 | colour2016 | colour2018 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |

and the other variable's data looks similar with column names being tied to the year the question was asked. Is there a way to not only show change of answer for both using ggplot2, but also track rate of change and display that visually by year?